# JavaEE: Using entity class from remote interface project

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, netbeans-8

I faced a very foolish problem, and reason is most likely my bad Java.

The issue is to create enterprise application with remote interface (separate project as NetBeans 8 desire) and entity classes. I've founded two manuals for NetBeans: with [Remote interface](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/entappclient.html) and with [Entities with facades](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/javaee-entapp-ejb.html).
But both of them describes only part of my situation.

The goal is to use entity classes (or some abstraction) not only from ejb project but also from remote interface projects. 
I've tried to do this by:

- creating entity classes in every of this projects separately and in both of them,
- creating facades for entity classes in remote interface project (NetBeans forbid it).

And all my attempts doesn't compile or work. So the question is how to properly solve this problem in NetBeans. The only solution I've found is to create Session Bean wrappers for every entity class but this doesn't smells good.

I will be glad to any advice.

Comment: Specifically "use entity classes from remote interface projects" is to create business method with return value of entity class.

Comment: What do you mean with "doesn't compile or work" ? If you mean that your presentation layer is not compiling because it need the entities, maybe you should compile the model (the entities classes) in a separate project, and include it in the presentation trough the project properties panel.

Comment: Thanks, @Leonardo.  Looks like the solution to my problem, and I most likely will do that way. But it seems to me that separation Remote Interface to individual project in NetBeans provides some other way to solve this problem. And this secret way looks interest for me).